# Trees from integers

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory, primes

A set of distinct positive integers is said to be a *prime tree of integers* if the graph obtained by letting the integers be its vertices, two of which are joined by an edge if (and only if) their sum is a prime, is a tree.

At most how many integers can such a set have if all of them are less than or equal to 100? Less than or equal to 1000?

Comment: Is the answer, or the method of finding it, particularly interesting? Otherwise this must surely be off-topic.

Comment: Turning a general undirected graph into a maximal tree (or a forest) by removing nodes is [known to be NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set#NP-hardness), so unless OP has some trick up his sleeve (he didn't respond to the comment asking if that's the case), this cannot be solved without brute force, and therefore is a computation problem rather than a puzzle.

Comment: A solution for N=100, found by integer programming: 2 4 10 12 16 18 20 22 26 32 34 36 40 42 43 44 46 48 50 52 56 58 59 60 62 66 68 70 72 74 75 76 78 80 82 84 90 92 94 96 (40 nodes)

Answer (score 4):

For `n=100`, is the answer?

> 26

How?

> There are 25 odd prime numbers up to 102. Subtract 2 from each of these and connect the resulting numbers directly to a `2` in the middle.

For other `n`

> For 1000, or any other values of `n`, we just need to find all odd prime numbers up to `n+2`, subtract `2` from them and connect each of the resultants to `2`. Voila! Your tree is ready. The size of the set is simply the number of prime numbers up to `n`.

How are we sure it's a tree?

> For each of the 25 elements connected to `100`, we have to ensure that there are no connections between any of them, to ensure acyclicity. Since they are all odd numbers `>=3`, their sum will be even and hence composite. This is sufficient to ensure that there are no edges between them.

Comment: Welcome to PSE, this is a really nice answer! :) This might be a good lower-bound candidate for now, though we shall see whether there is a better answer or this is already optimal. (Namely, maybe it is possible to have multiple edges with the same sum of primes.)

Comment: E.g. for $n = 6$, your method will give an answer of $4$ (as the odd primes up to $6 + 2 = 8$ are $3, 5, 7$). But the optimal answer should be $5$, achieved by either $\{1, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ or $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Can you think of a failing case for larger n? Or does the strategy fail only for small n?

Comment: It seems to me that there's nothing special about `2` in this construction. Replacing it with any other integer would generate a set of numbers with the same property. In particular, `3` and `1` can be easily seen to generate the same size tree as `2`.

Comment: I agree. 2 is an example, and this probably works with a host of other central numbers too. I see that the question has been closed as off-topic, but I'd still like to hear what the OP had in mind. @Bernardo Recamán Santos